# Sphinx: cross-reference indexed item

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, cross-reference

How can I cross-reference an indexed item inside a reStructuredText document?

For example, how can I cross-reference SectionB:

```
.. index::
    pair: SectionA; SectionB

SectionB
--------

SectionB description.
```

I tried using the index labels in references, such as:

```
:ref:`SectionB`
```

but this does not work.

Comment: are you really using :ref:'SectionB' instead of :ref:\`SectionB\` ?  you should be using backticks...

Comment: I am using backticks, but Markdown uses them as inline code spans so I just changed the example to use ''

Answer (score 3):

see: [Cross-referencing arbitrary locations](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/markup/inline.html#cross-referencing-arbitrary-locations)

in the Sphinx documentation.

I think what you might be missing is a reference label,

Try something like:

```
.. index::
pair: SectionA; SectionB

.. _section-b-label:

SectionB
--------

SectionB description.
```

and then elsewhere do:

```
:ref:`section-b-label`
```

Comment: I know I can use reference labels. What I was trying to avoid is having to add both the index and the reference label. It seems a bit redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx (now, since v1.4 in 2016) has an [autosectionlabel extension](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosectionlabel.html) that does exactly what you want:

> This extension allows you to refer sections its title. This affects to
> the reference role (ref).
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> A Plain Title
> -------------
>
> This is the text of the section.
>
> It refers to the section title, see :ref:`A Plain Title`.
> ```
>
> Internally,
> this extension generates the labels for each section. If same section
> names are used in whole of document, any one is used for a target by
> default. The autosectionlabel_prefix_document configuration variable
> can be used to make headings which appear multiple times but in
> different documents unique.

Answer (score 0):

This options still does not seem possible without adding in custom labels.
There is an issue open at https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1671

It is possible to link to glossary terms using `:term:`, and index links ideally would be possible and added to the [arbitrary links docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html?highlight=arbitrary#cross-referencing-other-items-of-interest)